# Is there a MessageCodeGenerator for the C++ quickfix?

Tags: c++, quickfix

In quickfixJ there's a way to automatically generate custom messages and custom field objects by using your custom Data Dictionary and running their MessageCodeGenerator task.

http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.1/usage/codegen.html

I now have to use the orginal quickfix (C++) for a new project I'm working on and I was wondering whether something similar exists out there for C++.

As an alternative (if nothing already exists) has anyone tried to use the Java based MessageCodeGenerator and modify the default java xslt templates to just spit out c++ files?

Also, if I'm going about this whole thing completely the wrong way, feel free to just point me to the right way of using the C++ quickfix as their site is a little "light" on custom examples (only has macro defs for fields..i saw nothing about messages)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QuickFIX pregenerates the messages and includes them in the distribution. Therefore, the code generation isn't part of the build process. However, you can regenerate the code using the scripts in the `spec` subdirectory. The generator is implemented using a combination of XSLT, shell scripts and Ruby code.

Run

`ruby Generate.rb`

to generate the message and field code, then

`generate_c++.sh` or `generate_c++.bat`

to generate the MessageCracker classes.

After the code is regenerated based on your modified FIX*.xml files, run the top level Makefile to rebuild the library.

Comment: Having a bit of trouble getting this all to work on my 64bit Win7 box. I'm trying it now on my linux box with a lot more success. Will have an update. Darn thing is taking forever.  I think the trick must be to remove unnecessary xml files for FIX version I'm not using?